# C# vertical tab control

Tags: c#, winforms

Can I make a tab control to look like the attached picture? I managed to add a tab control, but the text is still vertical. And I would want it to be horizontal.

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is an MSDN article about how to achieve this. [How to: Display Side-Aligned Tabs with TabControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404305.aspx)

> The following procedure shows how to render right-aligned tabs, with the tab text running from left to right, by using the "owner draw" feature.

Answer (score 8):

Try this [TabStrip](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14298/TabStrip-Control) control. I believe this is what you want.

Comment: Just checked myself - solution by Lloyd is much simpler than the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is default selected color

```
private void tabControl1_DrawItem(Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
...
if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected)
    {

        // Draw a different background color, and don't paint a focus rectangle.
        _textBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, e.Bounds);
    }
    else
    {
        _textBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.WhiteSmoke, e.Bounds); 
    }
...
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bwAf.png)