# What technique will I use if i want to change this panel when I click a button in VB

Tags: vb.net, system, panel

I just have it in my mind. And I can't explain it so here it goes.

A system that only uses 1 form?

It have a two panel, left and right.
The left is consist of buttons
Then the right is associated on the buttons and will change whether what button will be clicked.
Any ideas?

Comment: That's essential what tabcontrols are for...

Comment: What user interface technology are you talking about? WinForms, WPF,ASP.NET?

Comment: Hi steve, Im using Windowsform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preference is to do this via custom controls, rather than panels... but panels can work too.

There are a number of ways to do this:

- Keep all of the controls layered on top of each other, and then set the Visible property to false for controls/panels you don't care about and to true for the Control/Panel that you do
- Move the controls you don't care about out of the visible area
- Remove/Add the Controls/Panels from Form's controls collection entirely
- I think you can also get a TabControl to put the tabs along the left side, with some formatting that looks more like buttons, such that what you want will be handled without needing to write any code to switch layouts

Any of those can work. Whichever option you use, I have two recommendation for controlling layout and making the transitions smooth.

1. Call `SuspendLayout()` before making any changes, and then call `ResumeLayout()` when you're done. This will help avoid stuttering or a partially rendered form.
2. Look at the TableLayoutPanel Control. This control will allow you to arrange your top-level panels so that they can be resized with proportion. If you also then dock your individual panels, you can quickly build your program so that it resizes correctly.

Comment: Cool, I want that SuspendLayout() that you're saying. But can I ask how to do when I hover to a button or click. It will have an effect?

Answer (score 1):

You can have several panels, one on top of another. Change their visibility, depending on which one you need at a given moment.

Option #2 would be using a [vertical tab control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991507/c-sharp-vertical-tab-control) (or a [tab strip](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14298/TabStrip-Control) - see another answer there).