# Changing application layout via buttons in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net

Currently I would like to program an application gathering forms that are callable with buttons on the side. For this, I am using the latest build of Visual Studio Community. One way I thought of would be to literally put all the form elements (textboxes, lists, etc.) in the application window and only enable them whenever the according button is clicked on. However, if this is the way to do it, I find it quite messy and unpractical, and I'm pretty sure there's another way around.

After some research, I have learned about the MDI layouts, but they don't suit my taste. I would like to keep everything in one single frame.

Could you give me a hand?

Comment: You can design the all the forms separately, then load them into a Panel as a **borderless** form (with their Dock() property set to Fill) making it look seamless.  To add a Form as a child control, however, you must set its [TopLevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.toplevel(v=vs.110).aspx) property to False at run-time before adding it to a Controls() collection.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [C# vertical tab control](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8991507/1115360)?